# Differential equations of the geodesics of a metric

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, tensors

I am a first course student in tensor calculus and there is a problem in my book that says:
If the metric $G=(g_{ij})$ for $(x^i)$ is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(x^1\right)^2 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

a.- Write the differential equations of geodesics in terms of the dependent variables $u=(x^1)^2$, $v=x^2$.

b.- Solve them.

But my problem is that I don't know how to solve subsection (a.-), could someone help me? I have no problem when solving the differential equations but the thing was that in the previous problems they were already given. Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: can elementary variational calculus be used?

Comment: or through the theory which says that the geodesics are characterized by a couple of second order nonlinear differential equations $$\frac{d^2x^i}{dt^2}+\sum_{jk}\Gamma^I{}_{jk}\frac{dx^j}{dt}\frac{dx^k}{dt}=0?$$